# Match four columns as a condition to complete left outer join

Tags: sql, sas, left-join, case-statement

I need to combine two tables with all columns in the first table (left outer join) and only one column in the second if the values in four columns match.

In other words, if the four columns match then `updatenotice` should equal the value in the second table (table `b`) If one of the columns is not a match then do not join the second table's value but keep `updatenotice` as is in the  first table (table `a`).

I am getting a syntax error at the case statement.

Here is my code:

```
proc sql;
create table UseLimit_updates as
select *
from work.updated_mwh as a
left outer join work.archive_dups as b
   on a.updatenotice=b.updatenotice
   case when a.res_id=b.res_id
     and a.limit_start_date=b.limit_start_date
     and a.limit_end_date=b.limit_end_date
     and a.created_date=b.created_date
     then a.updatenotice=b.updatenotice
 else a.updatenotice='A'
end;
quit;
```

Comment: Please clarify: a) is it Oracle RDBMS or other? b) what is the error message, c) have you tried `a.*` instead of `*`?

Comment: This is a proc sql statement inside SAS. I did not try a.*

Comment: "all columns in the first table (left outer join) and only one column in the second" - ah! so @forpas answer looks correct: `case`-expression + `a.*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case statement must be included in the select part:

```
select 
  case when b.updatenotice is null then a.updatenotice else b.updatenotice end,
  <rest of the columns of work.updated_mwh>
from work.updated_mwh as a
left join work.archive_dups as b
on 
  a.res_id=b.res_id and 
  a.limit_start_date=b.limit_start_date and 
  a.limit_end_date=b.limit_end_date and 
  a.created_date=b.created_date
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `coalesce()` is more concise:

```
proc sql;
create table UseLimit_updates as
    select . . .,
           coalesce(b.updatenotice, a.updatenotice, 'A') as updatenotice
    from work.updated_mwh a left join
         work.archive_dups b
         on a.updatenotice = b.updatenotice and
            a.limit_start_date = b.limit_start_date and
            a.limit_end_date = b.limit_end_date and
            a.created_date = b.created_date;
    end;

quit;
```

Your code also suggests that you want `'A'` as the default if both the other values are missing.

Comment: I want to be sure that the record with the latest date stays as 'A' and the older dates are changed to 'D'. None of the values will ever be null.